# for heavy graphics apps in c# which will be more efficient double buffering or Buffered Graphics?

Tags: c#, user-interface, graphics, bufferedimage, doublebuffered

hello i have a heavy graphics application where i have to draw the graphics in 2-10 seconds every time this time varies depending upon the source application which is sending data to my application via UDP;

i have some static graphics there is no change in them some are semi dynamic that means some time they are updated and normally remains unchanged and all other graphics are dynamic there are about 8000 approx  objects that are dynamic

i am working in c# and learn the two techniques given in title which one will be more efficient in this case help required

thanx in advance;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How large are your objects?

One probably can't predict what's more efficient here, it depends on everything, type of objects, size of objects, complexity of converting data to visible graphics and most of all the speed of your internet connection will limit your application.

In the end you probably want to try both and measure their performance. Even then you might want to implement it as a setting so the user can flip between the two.